# Fade in text and keep it faded in on (quick) repeated function calls

Tags: jquery

I have a site where a user can check several checkboxes, and the user will usually check many of them in quick succession, or just one-two. 
On each update an ajax-script is run and the change saved to a database.

Now, some users felt that they needed a confirmation that their changes have been saved, so I'm trying to put together a simple js/jquery function the ajax-function can call on success. That's simple enough with a jquery $(object).html().fadein().delay().fadout(), however, I'm not able to figure ut how to make this text **stay faded in** when the user keeps clicking on new checkboxes (say, within 4s of the previous one).

I also have an issue with fadein() not working the first time but I've read that this might be solved with putting it inside a window.onLoad()?

TLDR:

- A "lazy" function that fades in text on first call, then waits 4s before fading out
- If it's called again during the 4s period, the 4s delay is "reset"
- After fading out it can be called as usual again

This is all I got really. I did manage to make something that kind of worked using a "text is being shown"-boolean but it froze the page while waiting for it's next call.

```
  $('#update_info').html("Dina val har uppdaterats").fadeIn(1400).delay(4000).fadeOut(1400);
```

UPDATE

Here are two of my attempts, the first just doesn't work, the text fades in and out incorrectly and it freezes all checkboxes while fading, and the other gives a maximum call stack size-error (I can't see why).

```
function fadeInText(){
if(upd==0){ //First call
  $('#update_info').html("Dina val har uppdaterats").fadeIn(2000);
  upd = 1;
  fadeInText();
}else{ //call when text is being displayed
  $('#update_info').stop();
  $('#update_info').delay(4000).fadeOut(2000);
  upd = 0;
};
```

.

```
function fadeInText(){
if(upd==0){ //First call
  $('#update_info').html("Dina val har uppdaterats").fadeIn(2000);
  upd = 1;
  fadeInText();
}else if(upd==1){ //call when text is being displayed
  $('#update_info').stop();
  upd = 2;
  fadeInText();
}else{
  upd = 1;
  $('#update_info').delay(4000).fadeOut(2000);
  upd = 0;
};
```

Comment: it seems to me that all you need is an if else statement. Second part of your tldr turned into code basically.

Comment: @Jabberwocky probably! But I'm not able to make it work, either I get issues like the page freezing during the delay or similar, or the text constantly staying visible etc. I've updated my reply with two of my attempts

Comment: can you post the click event handler too?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I call the fadeInText() from the success: "event"(?) of the ajax function which is run every time a checkbox changes state. 

  $(":checkbox").on("click", function(event) {

    $.ajax({,......,
      success: function() {
        fadeInText();}
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to call **stop** function on the element when the user clicks the next element?

http://api.jquery.com/stop/